# Switching particles for antiparticles in Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, antimatter, charge-conjugation

While studying, I found a problem involving $e^-\nu_e$ and $e^-\bar{\nu}_e$ scattering, though this could also apply to $e^- e^-$ and $e^- e^+$ scattering if we wanted to keep everything within QED.

[image]

After calculating $<\mathcal{M}^2>$ for the first diagram, the solution claims that
to compute the amplitude of the second diagram, it is enough to perform $p_1 \leftrightarrow p'_1$, the swapping of the momenta associated to the neutrino, in the first amplitude.

Intuitively, one can "rotate" the upper part of the diagram, thus obtaining fermionic lines that go "against time", meaning they must be antifermionic, and momenta would automatically be swapped. Is this a correct way to think about it?

Is there a Feynman rule in general for this kind of behavior? Maybe a short proof that doesn't involve computing the second amplitude as a whole in order to check, and also that could work in general?

**EDIT:** It might be important to add we are treating all particles as being massless, or at least in the ultrarelativistic
limit.

Comment: If you have the Feynman rules that you are using, what did you see when you started writing the fermion line for the top of both diagrams?

Comment: @Triatticus For the diagram on the left I get $\bar{u}_n(p_1,s_1)(V)u_n(p'_1,s'_1)$, where $V$ is the vertex factor, and for the diagram on the right, I get the same except $u$ and $\bar{u}$ are replaced by $v$ and $\bar{v}$. This doesn't explain the momentum swapping, since the operators are ordered the same, and in the relativistic limit, the completeness relations are also the same for the fermionic and antifermionic solutions.

Comment: Ok, I just noticed momenta are indeed swapped, since we started at the opposite side of the diagram. Indeed, since completeness relations are the same for fermions and antifermions, swapping momenta is enough. Thank you very much for your input, @Triatticus.

Comment: I'm glad you came to a satisfying conclusion, I hadn't necessarily intended to lead you to an answer with that and was just curious on what you had done :)

Comment: @Triatticus Feel free to add that as an answer and I will accept, it pointed me in the right direction for sure.

Comment: You could show all the work you've done, and the realization, and actually answer your own question actually. I didn't provide anything but a slight hint I guess. You actually did the legwork and the analysis.